# Azure Runbook query running jobs

Tags: powershell, azure-runbook

Azure Powershell runbook, scheduled to run **every 1h**.
The script runs "Invoke-AzVMRunCommand" to call a Powershell script on remote VM locally.

The problem -
sometimes it runs **longer than 1h** and overlaps with next in the schedule, and the second run fails with an error related to "Invoke-AzVMRunCommand" :
*"Run command extension execution is in progress. Please wait for completion before invoking a run command."*

The question - how to query if the runbook job is currently running.
We can not change schedule.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one does the check:

```
$jobs = Get-AzAutomationJob -ResourceGroupName $rgName -AutomationAccountName $aaName -RunbookName $runbook

$runningCount = ($jobs | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq "Running" }).count

if (($jobs.status -contains "Running" -And $runningCount -gt 1 ) -Or ($jobs.Status -eq "New"))
{   
    Write-Output "`n This runbook [$runbook] execution is stopped - there is another job currently running. Execution will start as per schedule next hour."
    Exit 1
} 
else
{
    Write-Output "`n Let's proceed with runbook [$runbook] execution - there are no interfering jobs currently running." | Out-File -Filepath StarStop.txt -Append
} #end of check runbook status
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Az PowerShell cmdlet [Get-AzAutomationJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/get-azautomationjob?view=azps-3.5.0) to check the status of the job. Also, based on that status you may decide to remove or set existing schedule using schedule related cmdlets from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/?view=azps-3.5.0).